# capybara use visit in a for loop

Tags: ruby, loops, xpath, capybara

I have a code which tries to visit several web pages and add them to favorites. As I figure, once you use visit, capybara can't continue with the rest of the commands, check the code below;

```
sub_menus = all('li a')
for i in 0..(sub_menus.length-1)
  if (sub_menus[i]['href'] == "http://intranet/Intranet/#") || (sub_menus[i]['href'] !~ /http:\/\/intranet(.*)/)
    next
  else
    visit sub_menus[i]['href']
    $links.push(sub_menus[i]['href'])
    find(:xpath , '//*[@id="AddFavorites_UC1_AddFavoriteButton"]').click
  end
  puts "hgfhf"
end
  p $links
  p $links.length
```

When I execute this code, visit and click work for one time only, but the for loop doesn't run a second time.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Yes. Use `sub_menus.each` instead of `for i in 0..(sub_menus.length-1)`.

Comment: Are you using this for testing or scraping? For scraping I find [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) orders of magnitude better.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :) didn't help with the problem though. I'm trying to automate some web page tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you go to another page element locator become invalid and you can't use it anymore. So you can't use `sub_menus` at another page.

Thus you should use something like:

```
links = all('li a').map { |el| el[:href] }
$links = []
links.each do |link|
  unless link !~ /http:\/\/intranet(.*)/
    visit link
    $links << link
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks  Andrey it worked. Another  question: some of the links I find have target attributes while others don't. I want to clean my array of the ones that have target attributes. How can I do that?

Comment: @AlperMermer Use array's `delete_if` method